# Can't open modal bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

When I click link,

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#report">
```

It shows modal well in 1-2 seconds but after that, the modal load page again. So, the content of modal is replaced by the page it loaded. Why?

```
<div id="report" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to post a [mcve] to debug this kind of problem.

Comment: Did you find any errors on the console?

Comment: No, it didn't return anything

Comment: Try replacing it with button, as said in the answers, tell us if that helps?

Comment: Your code appears to work fine: [https://jsfiddle.net/97k523g2/](https://jsfiddle.net/97k523g2/).

Comment: You are probably using an older version of bootstrap which replaces the content of the modal with the content of the url in href. See my answer. Which version of bootstrap are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because you are using the `a` tag with a `href` attribute to open the modal. It will then replace the modal with the content of your `href`, which is the current page. Try to use a `button` or something to open your modal:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#report">Launch modal</button>
```

EDIT: for the ones that don't believe this is possible and are downvoting me, here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3tny40bo/3/) with shows exactly the same behavior that @thai6070 is describing in his question.. This option is deprecated in newer versions of bootstrap.

Comment: Some versions of bootstrap do this.

Comment: @dfsq I think it doesn't reload the whole page, I think it loads the content of the page in the modal.

Comment: Wow, didn't know that was possible with bootstrap! Its actually a pretty cool function! Too bad it is deprecated..

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Paste this code into your `head` tag.